# Redirecting keydown by hook in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, hook, keypress

I want to write an application like hotkey helpers for games, for example, in Warcraft 3, I use numpad keys for some reason. Is it possible to send a "Numpad 1 key pressed" message to the OS by pressing the "X" key? I've been trying to do this using hooks but I couldn't figure out. I hope I was clear.

I've used this class for hooks: [Global System Hooks in .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/globalsystemhook.aspx).

Simply my code is like this:

```
globalKeyboardHook hook = new globalKeyboardHook(); // A Global Hook

private void btnHook_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    hook.hook(); // Set the hook
    hook.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.X); // Hook the X key
    // i removed other hooks purify the code, six hooks total.
    hook.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(hook_KeyDown); // add eventhandler
    Program.hookActive = true; // inform the program that hook is active.
    Guncelle(); // update form components (buttons enabling/disabling according to hook status etc.)
}

private void hook_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    KeyEventArgs k = new KeyEventArgs(Keys.NoName);
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.X:
            k = new KeyEventArgs(Keys.NumPad1);
            OnKeyDown(k);
            break;
            // i removed other cases to purify the code, six cases total.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the WinAPI `SendInput()` or `keyb_event()` calls. For example:

```
keybd_event(VK_NUMPAD1, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, now two different problems have spawned. it worked on applications like notepad, but its not working on Warcraft-like big games. Second problem is, whenever i hit "X" key once, the numpad1 key simulates 4 times.